# xamarin (or other) mobile application tutorial screens localization

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, graphics, localization

I am working on mobile application in xamarin.forms and thinking about 3-5 pages tutorial screens for users. what is the best technique to localize them ? I was trying to google this question but failed to find anything. currently, I have the following ideas and before starting to test them decided to ask here
1. localization in graphics, 3-5 page for 3-5 dpi per language bring lot of additional size to package. the worse idea I think. I don't have any other graphics assets to localize, so I don't think different apk is a way to go
2. I am thinking about to put image as a page background and place text in labels with absolute layout (xaml or programmatically). it seems it should work may be with some font size adjustments due to different dpi
3. I found that I can export drawings and text as svg file from photoshop, and quickly find some packages to work with svg, so, it seems that it may be one more way to go

but I'm sure I am not the first with this problem and don't want to reinvent the wheel ;)

any ideas will be greatly appreciated
I am not looking for specific xamarin.forms solution, just for ideas

Comment: If you don't want additional size to package. How about download these images from your sever? With those who don't have an Internet connecting, you can use 
default images.

Comment: hmm, thanks, that's may be one more way to go :)

Answer (score 0):

Your best option will be localized strings, for each Language, and then use those strings in your screens with your images.

You can also have localized images, but as you've said, it will make the application size bigger.

You can read more about Xamarin.Forms localization [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/localization/text?tabs=macos)

Comment: thanks, the app is already localized. mostly my question was about best way of localizing images.